# Is it possible to force collectionView not to reuse visible cells?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` doc says: "*This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available ..*" When is a cell available? How can I force collectionView not to reuse cells that are visible?

Could it help, if for `indexPath` I pass a nil argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOT the visible cells get reused, but the ones which where visible, but at the moment are off-screen.

This is how the Guidelines tells us to do!!!

Reusable Views Improve Performance.

"Collection views employ a view recycling program to improve efficiency. As views move offscreen, they are removed from view and placed in a reuse queue instead of being deleted. As new content is scrolled onscreen, views are removed from the queue and repurposed with new content."

Check out this link to understand better:

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html